Designing SQL Postgres Relations Table for Editing Entered Documents and Undo Functionality
I'm currently working on a system where users can edit entered documents in a PostgreSQL database. The functionality entails allowing users to click on a document to edit it, effectively creating a copy where they can modify its lines. These edits can include actions like making batch reservations. Once edits are completed, the user can save the changes, updating the original document, or cancel the edit, reverting back to the original state.
Here are some key considerations for the database schema:
Editing Documents: Users should be able to select a document for editing, which will create a copy where they can make modifications such as adding or removing lines, adjusting quantities, or applying batch reservations.
Undo Functionality: After initiating edits, users should have the option to save the changes, updating the original document with the edited version, or cancel the edit, reverting the document back to its original state.
Given these requirements, I'm seeking advice on the optimal design for the relations table in PostgreSQL. Specifically, I'm unsure about how to structure the schema to efficiently manage the editing process and facilitate undo functionality.
I see two possibilities:
// one table for both
Table document
  id
  status (DRAFT | ENTERED)
  edited_by_id int (FK to document)


// one table for each
Table document
  id
  status (DRAFT | ENTERED)

Table document_edit
  id
  editing_document_id int (FK to document)

Should I create separate tables for storing the original and edited versions of the document and lines, or is there a more streamlined approach?
Any insights, recommendations, or examples of database schema designs that could help me implement this functionality effectively in PostgreSQL would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would first question why you are using documents to do what are independent operations?

Could you please elaborate on the question, as I'm not sure I understand correctly. I will describe the process that takes place. The documents table is a simplified model of one of the main document types that occur in the application: orders, stock documents and invoices. The system has a batch booking system. So each 'document' is linked to > 'document_sku' and then > 'document_batch' - 'batch_reservation'. 'document/order/stock_batch' reserves stock via the 'batch_reservation' table. If I understand correctly, you are referring to operations on the frontend where the user e.g.

opens a modal and edits the information there? The problem with this is that, e.g. on orders/releases, an increase in quantity must involve the creation of a temporary reservation (for the duration of the document edit), a decrease in quantity on goods receipt adjustments or corrections also. Hence my question, as I have never had a similar situation where editing and further saving something involves such an advanced logical process. I did some research but could not find enough information.

When saving an edit, the temporary edit is deleted and the changes made to the original rows, when cancelled, everything returns to its previous state. The 'one table for both' solution seems tempting, as it will only require adding one/two columns to each table instead of creating a copy of each table associated with the document. However, I don't know if such a mixing of already saved documents in the lead with those from editing in one table is good practice.


Add the explanation in your comments as update to question. 2) In 1) include a better description of what you are calling a 'document' and where the information is being stored. Right now I cannot figure out whether you are referring to something like a JSON data structure or an entry form.


you can create a SCD table with an extra value adding with start and end_date, iscurrent to capture the values and also can give a flagging value to differentiate the data.
https://setumo.medium.com/slowly-changing-dimensions-scd-in-azure-synapse-analytics-5e7aefa31564
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/scd-type2-implementation-in-python-95bb08878ce2

This looks encouraging, I've done some reading and I have it seems that this process in postgres can be done using the pgaudit extension.

Please provide more detail here, Links can die someday!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
